# Set up internal DNS to point to that DNS server?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, routing, dhcp

I have Windows Server 2008 running on my network with the following properties:

- Internal IP: 192.168.1.100
- External IP: 242.24.124.12

Now I have registered a domain (example.com) and have it pointing to the external IP of my server.

Now all is fine and dandy, when I go to example.com, I get pointed to my server.

What I want to do, is set up a DNS on said server, and have it redirect requests to example.com to my internal IP, from internal network.

MSPainted:

[image: Topology]

So what I want to happen:

When an external host connects to example.com, they use their default DNS and it resolves to the external 242 IP. When an internal hosts goes to example.com, they use the internal server as a DNS which responds with its own 192.168.1.100 IP.

Is it possible to set this up with Windows Server 2008?

What I was thinking is install the DNS role on my windows server, then create an A record for example.com pointing to itself, and have my DHCP server serve 192.168.1.100 as the DNS server. But how would I set it up so my internal hosts use the real DNS when making requests for other domains? Is there anything else I must do to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

It should be. What you really want to do is hijack the example.com domain and forward all other queries.

Comment: Just want to add that this is ridiculously easy using Unbound as I do it all the time. They do have a Windows version, you might check it out: http://unbound.net/ should be a lot less overhead than running Windows DNS.

Comment: heres the technet documentation on Forwarders: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754941.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand everything you descibe correctly, but I'll give it a try.

Each application uses different ports, and the traffic need to be redireted from youre router. When the router reveives packages from outside to fx your domain port 22 (ssh), then you need to portforwad these packages to a specific IP on your inside network. So when you are outside your net, the command to connect via ssh would be "ssh www.yourdomain.com" and the router forwards you to your machine on your inside net; hence the machine you declare as target through your router settings.

In case you use DHCP then your router sends DNS settings to units on your internal network. You can set specific DNS servers there. These would be distributed automatically.

You can also setup your machines with static IP and set DNS per machine.

Comment: Ok, i see it has nothing to do with what i wrote.

Comment: There are different possibilities. What about the client hosts file, where you can predefine domaine name resolutions(windows)? Another possibilie could be an internal proxy, maybe you could setup some rules for redirection.